# Joining two tables and getting rows as columns

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables. One is a transaction table of user id with following details.

```
user_id Product_id timestamp transaction_id
123     A_1                   ID1
123     A_2                   ID1
124     A_1                   ID2 
125     A_2
```

Now there is a product_id mapping with the division to which the product belongs

Mapping:

```
Product_id   Division
A_1          Grocery
A_2          Electronics and so on
```

I need a final table where I have one record for each user id and the corresponding items bought in each division as separate columns. Like

```
User_ID   Grocery  Electronics
123        1       1
124        1       0
```

I did something like this:

```
select user_id, case (when Division ="Grocery" then count(product_id) else 0) end as Grocery 
when Division="Electronics" then count(product_id) else 0) end as Electronics 
from 
( select user_id, a.product_id, b.division from transact as a
left join 
mapping b
on a.product_id=b.product_id
) 
group by user_id

Does this sound good?
```

Comment: MySql <> SQL Server. Pick one.

Comment: Any sql. That was just to post it to many users

Comment: There's also the PIVOT function, supported by SQL Server and not by MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

When you use conditional aggregation, the `case` is the argument to the aggregation function:

```
select user_id,
       sum(case when m.Division = 'Grocery' then 1 else 0 end) as Grocery, 
       sum(case when m.Division = 'Electronics' then 1 else 0 end) as Electronics 
from transact t left join 
     mapping m
     on t.product_id = m.product_id
group by user_id
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/13413/2/0)

In addition:

- Your table aliases should be abbreviations for the table.  Makes the code easier to understand.
- You don't need a subquery.
- Use single quotes for string constants.  This is the SQL standard.

Comment: count(product_id) is not right then?. Will give error?

Comment: `COUNT` will work, but you still have to use conditional aggregation e.g: `COUNT(CASE WHEN m.division = 'Electronics' THEN m.product_id END)`

Comment: @Manish . . . Your query should generate an error in any database, except MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I added an SQL Fiddle if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamic version of Gordon Linoff's answer, which uses conditional aggregation. This works for SQL-Server.

```
DECLARE @sql1 VARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @sql2 VARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @sql3 VARCHAR(4000) = ''

SELECT @sql1 = 
'SELECT
    t.user_id
'

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   , SUM(CASE WHEN m.division = ''' + division + ''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [' + division + ']' + CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT division FROM Mapping
)t
ORDER BY division

SELECT @sql3 = 
'FROM Transact t
LEFT JOIN Mapping m
    ON m.product_id = t.product_id
GROUP BY t.user_id'

PRINT (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
EXEC (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/13413/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding it can be acheived using PIVOT also

```
declare @transact table (user_id int,product_id varchar(5),transaction_id varchar(5))
    insert into @transact (user_id,product_id,transaction_id)values (123,'A_1','ID1'),(123,'A_2','ID1'),(124,'A_1','ID2'),(125,'A_2',NULL)

    declare @mapping table (product_id varchar(5),division varchar(20))
    insert into @mapping (product_id,division)values ('A_1','Grocery'),('A_2','Electronics')

    select * from (
    select t.user_id,tt.division as Division,tt.product_id As product_id from @transact t
    left join @mapping tt
    on t.product_id = tt.product_id)T
    PIVOT(COUNT(product_id)FOR division IN ([Grocery],[Electronics]))P
```